Using julia with multiple people
I want to be able to code in a jupyter environment, using Julia, with multiple people at the same time. I know there's visual studio with live share, but that depends on one person sharing their code.
I want to be able to use it independently. Comparable to writing a LaTeX document together in Overleaf, just with coding.
I tried solving this with replit, but i can only get a jupyter environment in a separate tab and to add to that, i can only use python not julia in that separate jupyter tab.
There might be an easy fix, but I'm not really experienced in programming, so any help is greatly appreciated.

"There might be an easy fix, but I'm not really experienced in programming..." It isn't really a matter of being experienced in programming. It is more of knowing what is available for teaching and training. "I want to be able to use it independently." I'm understanding from that you'd like each user to have their own 'instance'? I think here covers that. I'll expand on that soon. But then you say, "writing a LaTeX document together in Overleaf" which sounds like collaboration. ...

 That level is harder. I had seen it back a couple of years ago with similarMyBinder-served sessions involving JupyterLab, see here but I haven't tried it in a while. And I don't know if it works with a Julia kernel? Oops, I should have tried what I referenced earlier. This and this are more informative than link in my ...

 first comment. They can use Julia independently by going to this GitHub repo and clicking on the 'launch binder' badge to start their own session. If you know what you are doing with the token and URL it is even possible to share that session. Not advised but possible. Howver, a true collaborative environment would be best. Aside from everything I've mentioned prior, I see there is JuliaHub. It seems it gives you 20 hours free. So maybe sign up & test and then sign ...

 up again with a different email or something right before your training stuff? Or ask them if they support giving credits for educators/trainers? (I should add in regards to my earlier suggestion of MyBinder-served session, that MyBinder use these days takes some patience as the free resources are limited. See manics' comment here.)

You may also find this discussion enlightening.
